# How many datapoints can be imported in OpenTSDB

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

What is the limit of number of datapoints that can be imported in OpenTSDB at a time. I have an input file with data like:

```
AnkitBhthansAir:src anjali$ head -10 OpenTSDB_Import.txt 
meterreadings 1406865600 10086 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406866500 10134 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406867400 9906 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406868300 9840 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406869200 9870 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406870100 9840 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406871000 9426 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406871900 9720 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406872800 9636 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
meterreadings 1406873700 9816 Building_id=1  interval=900 measure_kind=12 service_kind=0 unit=72
```

It has 35000+ records. I am trying to import these into OpenTSDB using command:

> import OpenTSDB.txt

But the OpenTSDB is not responding. Is there any upperlimit in number if datapoints we can import

All I see in log is this information:

```
13:29:20.031 INFO  [ZooKeeper.<init>] - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost sessionTimeout=5000 watcher=org.hbase.async.HBaseC$
13:29:20.173 INFO  [ClientCnxn.startConnect] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
13:29:20.174 INFO  [HBaseClient.getDeferredRoot] - Need to find the -ROOT- region
13:29:20.960 INFO  [ClientCnxn.primeConnection] - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
13:29:21.168 INFO  [ClientCnxn.readConnectResult] - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14f46fdce3f$
13:29:21.449 INFO  [HBaseClient.handleMetaZnode] - Connecting to .META. region @ 127.0.0.1:43800
13:29:21.758 INFO  [ZooKeeper.close] - Session: 0x14f46fdce3f0007 closed
13:29:21.759 INFO  [ClientCnxn.run] - EventThread shut down
13:29:22.107 INFO  [HBaseClient.discoverRegion] - Added client for region RegionInfo(table="tsdb", region_name="tsdb,,1439194770946.c4c2d4f2aacc$
13:29:22.187 INFO  [HBaseClient.discoverRegion] - Added client for region RegionInfo(table="tsdb-uid", region_name="tsdb-uid,,1436197167572.2277$
13:29:25.783 INFO  [TSDB.shutdown] - Flushing compaction queue
13:29:25.900 INFO  [HBaseClient.removeClientFromCache] - Lost connection with the .META. region
```